# What should happen with this list-based question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

A [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127929/inconsistencies-between-the-star-wars-movies-star-wars-the-clone-wars) was closed today, citing this question as a duplicate:

[What continuity problems have Star Wars: The Clone Wars created?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23814/what-continuity-problems-have-star-wars-the-clone-wars-created)

The answer there cites a couple examples and the answer was accepted but the list doesn't appear to be exhaustive in any way. It seems like its lack of completeness is what prompted the user to ask the duplicate question in the first place.

What should happen here? Should the old question be resurrected (not even sure what that would mean in this context...)? Should it be closed for being too open-ended to build a good list? What does that mean for the duplicate question since its scope is a little more narrow?

Comment: The question from 2012 sounds awfully broad. It seems like the sort of thing that would get closed if it were asked today.

Comment: Do you think the question that got marked as a dup today should be re-opened given its narrower scope?

Comment: I don’t know. I’m not all that familiar with Star Wars.

Comment: [Your comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127929/inconsistencies-between-the-star-wars-movies-star-wars-the-clone-wars#comment321506_127929) on the dupe question summarizes what should be done (wait for a better answer on the original, close the new one as a dupe).

Comment: "A better answer should be added to the older question rather than re-asking the same question hoping for a better answer." How can an asker do that? ... A bounty. OK then: How can a 1 rep use bounties? They can't. - The onus is on our high rep users to add said bounty. Where's @Wad? ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should have happened, if your are correct about the new OP's motivations, is a bounty.

Although, SE says something like, "If this does not answer your question, please ask a new one." So the *OP's* course of action is to edit and vie for reopening. Championing the question is also your prerogative, should you wish to.

It's not unheard of for a new question to make a dupe out of an old one, but it is rare.

'Should be resurrected' doesn't mean anything here; it (the old one) is not on hold or closed (nor has it ever been; no edit history).

It is not too open-ended to build a good list, but it'd likely be quite extensive.

IMO, it's of limited use (meaning use DVs, not VTCs). I really have no interest in pointing out every inconsistency in Star Wars, as I have no respect for any canon that has produced one.

Comment: So you have no respect for any canon anywhere?

Comment: @anaranjada "[It's real easy for me.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29624744#29624744) There's 3 movies, 2 ewok specials, and a handful of books published before 1995."

Comment: @Mazura My brother in canon. I'm glad I finally found you. I also refuse to call *Star Wars* "A New Hope". I'm curious how you feel about: the Decipher Collectable Card Game, the West End Games Star Wars RPG, and the X-Wing and TIE Fighter series of video games from the early 90s. I maybe wouldn't say they're canon, but they all have a special place in my heart.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Seriously. All the kids have chased the rest of us away. I never knew about the card game, but the RPG and even *Alliance* for PC count; let's call those the EU. I have dubbed this all, M-Canon (Mazura-canon ;)

Comment: @Mazura Nice. M-Canon. I'll bookmark this and refer to this canon with a link to here in future *Star Wars* answers.

Comment: Oh wow, in Harmy's edition it's just called SW. - No episode number, no subtitle. ESB is called "Episode V" though, and RotJ: "Episode VI" with their respective subtitles. I knew there was a reason I think the tag "Star Wars" should be *The Star Wars Saga*. *Star Wars* is a single movie released in 1977. This tag description is inaccurate: "that began in 1977 with 'A New Hope.'"

Comment: Each subsequent release (of the same movie) should have it's own tag.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - If I work up the gall, I'll make it a meta question. [(chat discussion)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29638810#29638810)

Comment: The answer to "who shot first" depends on which tag for SW you used. End of freaking story.